# How do I designate a nameserver with my registrar using the IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have the need to enter in 2 nameservers for my registrar, however GoDADDY will not allow IP addresses because of 1.2.3.4 will resolve to ".4" since that would be the domain for a domain name.

I am attempting to set up a nameserver using bind and seem to be having a chicken and egg scenario where I need the domain to resolve before the nameservers can be pointed to.

Is there a step I'm missing where domain names "ns1.example.com" must first be setup elsewhere? I could be setting up bind incorrectly, but it still doesn't solve my issue of setting pointing the registrar to my actual nameserver. Is there any special syntax that will allow me to enter in the IP address for my 2 nameservers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to setup custom name servers so you can give any web-hosting client of yours pretty name servers with your domain in them **(NS1/NS2.MyCoolCompany.com)**, as opposed to showing that you are actually reselling hosting when you tell them to point to **(NS1/NS2.MyUnCoolHostingCompany.com)**.

Setting up custom name servers with GoDaddy would simply be a process of logging into your account and then getting to the control panel for the domain name that you want to use as your custom name servers, be sure you click on the domain name to get into the more detailed info for it and don't go to the domain's dashboard. Then just click on **[Host Summary (Add)]** at the bottom-left of the page.

Add **[NS1]** as the host name and then enter an IP for it, then **(Add)** again and do the same thing for **[NS2]**. It's Ok if you have them both point to the same IP address if you were only given one by your web-host.

Doing the above steps affectively registers your domain as a name server although you might have to wait up to 12 hours before you can point to it. Then it's just a matter of popping into WHM or another control panel software and setting your server's name servers to also reflect the **(NS1/2.YourCoolCompany.com)** host name, or you can add it manually as well.

Comment: Are the steps in your second and third paragraph specific to godaddy? I am doing this because I am setting up bind on my server.

Comment: The steps for registering your domain name as a name server was specific to GoDaddy. Basically what you do is tell your domain Registar whoever they might be, that you are going to run your own custom name servers. You do this by going to the **[Host Summary]** in GoDaddy, some others call it register custom name servers.

Comment: You setup your DNS zones on your server with bind, and by registering your domain name as a name server with your Registrar, this now allows your server to respond to DNS queries using the hosts you setup (NS1/2).

Comment: That worked. I also had an issue with the zone file bind was using for setup. With the named-checkzone command and with your tip I was able to get the dns server and the glue records set up correctly.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you, it's hard to find help on this subject because there are too many terms out there for the same thing (custom NS, private NS, DNS hosts, and glue records).

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to set up ns1/2.example.com as the authoritative nameservers for example.com, you must set up *glue records* in your parent zone (ie, GoDaddy.) Most registrars will let you do this, but they often hide it out of the way. Look for 'register a nameserver' or similar, then once registered you should be able to list them (by name) as the nameservers for your domain.

Comment: Thanks. The terminology "glue records" was helpful. I did some more reading on how that works and it turns out to be exactly my problem.